# Slatejs editor.selection returns null on popovers?

Tags: slatejs

I created a slatejs rich text editor with voids, but I have a problem which is I can't get the current selection while I am doing actions inside the popover. However, I recreated the problem here [on sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-data-gird-with-slatejs-mz27y?file=/src/SimplePopover.tsx).

- **additional info**

  - if you need to know why I want to get the `editor.selection` inside a popover? I need that because sometimes I do actions inside the popover and I need to update the document manula using `Trsnform.setNodes(editor,newData,at:{editor.selection.path})`
- **my goal** is to get `editor.selection` in `SimplePopover.tsx:64` in my [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-data-gird-with-slatejs-mz27y?file=/src/SimplePopover.tsx).

Comment: Theres an error in the sandbox

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into the same problem a while back.I found a work around to this by saving the selection in a state when the button  is clicked and after everything is done, during insertion use `Transforms.select(editor,selection); Transforms.insertNodes(editor,node)`

or specify the location `Transforms.insertNodes(editor,node,{at:selection})`

Answer (score 0):

I see an error on the sandbox, but have suggestion for you, if I have understood your question correctly, the component invoking SimplePopover might be getting re-rendered, resulting in selection being lost. You can maintain that, invoke popover with it, have `editor.selection = props.selection` and clear selection on closing the popover.